# Reverting changes in Git and keeping later changesets

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-rebase, git-revert

I'm unsure if I wrongly understood how the revert works or is it Visual Studio just doing something weird.
Firstly I made the following commit inside of master branch

```
WriteNumbers(100, 2);

void WriteNumbers(int toWhere, int dividableByWhat)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= toWhere; i++)
        if (i % dividableByWhat == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Then I created new branch, switched to it and just added the new line as follows

```
WriteNumbers(100, 2);
WriteNumbers(100, 3);

void WriteNumbers(int toWhere, int dividableByWhat)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= toWhere; i++)
        if (i % dividableByWhat == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I merged this branch into master. Afterwards I made another commit in master where I just added a new `WriteNumbers(100, 4);` line.

Now from my understanding If I revert the changeset which introduced `WriteNumbers(100, 3);` I should still have `WriteNumbers(100, 4);` in my file but that just doesn't seem to be case, at least in Visual Studio.
[image: Trying to revert a changeset]

[image: Wrong merge options]

As it can be seen when I run revert on changeset, I get option to either delete both lines (as was before I merged the second branch into master) or to keep both changes (which is also invalid state). Is there any other way to just delete `WriteNumbers(100, 3);` line or I'm just doing something wrongly?

Comment: As far as Git itself is concerned, running `git revert` on the intermediate commit will produce a *merge conflict*, because the idea of removing one `WriteNumbers` call is fine but the *line to be removed* is supposed to be surrounded *above* by another `WriteNumbers` call, and *below* by a *blank line*. But the line to be removed in the current file has another `WriteNumbers` call below. Git can't (and is not supposed to) understand that it's OK to remove the line in spite of the context not matching. You, as the programmer, are expected to figure out the right result.

Comment: In command-line Git, you get a conflict and *you* provide the *right result*. How that's represented in any particular IDE such as Visual Studio is up to the IDE, not up to Git.

Answer (score 0):

When you revert a commit which changes a line that was altered in later commits (or its surrounding lines were altered), then you get a *merge conflict*. You must resolve this conflict manually and that is what Visual Studio is asking you to do.

Git nor Visual Studio can know which lines are the correct ones after the revert, so you have to pick.